# If 28 lines are drawn,how many vertices does the polygon have?

Tags: geometry, polygons

The vertices of a polygon are connected to each other by drawing some lines. If 28 lines are drawn,how many vertices does the polygon have?

Comment: Hint: how many lines do you need to connect _one_ vertex of an $n$-gon to the rest?

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if one vertex is connected to every other vertex, or if EVERY vertex is connected to every other vertex.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Number of pairs of two out of n number of vertices:-
$$^nC_2=28 \implies n^2-n-56=0$$

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for $n$ for which the [triangular](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) number $T_{n-1}=28$. This $n$ is $8$.

Consider the eight vertices to be eight party guests, and ask how many toasts you hear when all guests toast with one another. Same principle.